# IOS Crashing on Testflight but works on emulator

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I have a serious issue guys. I have been building a flutter app which has been working well on emulator. However, while building for test flight, it keeps crashing.

I have tried a lot of things which includes regenerating the folder, flutter clean etc but it keeps crashing on real devices on test flight.  This is painful to see as I don't have any way to debug this. I attached crash report though. Can someone relate with this?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda2aa48 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde4a8d8 pthread_kill + 208 (pthread.c:1609)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018e9910c0 abort + 120 (abort.c:118)
3   Flutter                         0x0000000102189b2c 0x101ea8000 + 3021612
4   Flutter                         0x0000000102189c5c 0x101ea8000 + 3021916
5   Flutter                         0x0000000102381100 0x101ea8000 + 5083392
6   Flutter                         0x00000001021eba54 0x101ea8000 + 3422804
7   Flutter                         0x0000000101eb7a10 0x101ea8000 + 64016
8   Flutter                         0x0000000101eccaf8 0x101ea8000 + 150264
9   Flutter                         0x0000000101ecc934 0x101ea8000 + 149812
10  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186d35d8c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2292 (UINib.m:390)
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001868d87dc -[UIStoryboard __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 280 (UIStoryboard.m:233)
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001868d8678 -[UIStoryboard _instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 124 (UIStoryboard.m:212)
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001868dbaa8 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 180 (UIApplication.m:4665)
14  UIKitCore                       0x000000018694fecc -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 276 (UIApplication.m:0)
15  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186cf7718 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 972 (UIApplication.m:4407)
16  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186b639ec -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 148 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:452)
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001869c6b00 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 96 (_UISceneLifecycleState.m:109)
18  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186aeb9f4 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 196 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:565)
19  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186c02204 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 240 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:514)
20  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186e2f064 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 732 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:564)
21  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186dbedac -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 336 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:470)
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001869c79e8 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block... + 188 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:73)
23  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186a842f8 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 812 (BSAnimationSettings+UIKit.m:50)
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001869c9778 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 248 (_UISceneSettingsDiffAction.m:23)
25  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186aaf530 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 356 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:58)
26  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186f0bbec __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.573 + 772 (UIScene.m:1775)
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001869f7f80 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 248 (UIScene.m:1476)
28  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186a3a3ec -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 264 (UIScene.m:1742)
29  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186b68684 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 548 (UIApplication.m:3900)
30  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186aad94c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 360 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:45)
31  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000194f4afc4 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 412 (FBSScene.m:439)
32  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000194f6d550 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.180 + 100 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:384)
33  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000194f2d714 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 232 (FBSWorkspace.m:352)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3ea9c _pthread_cond_updateval + 268 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3ea9c _pthread_cond_updateval + 268 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3ea9c _pthread_cond_updateval + 268 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda24b70 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25194 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844caad0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844cebb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844e1d8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x0000000185c20b6c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   Foundation                      0x0000000185c5fd6c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000186c94950 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 512 (UIEventFetcher.m:1167)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000185c6d64c __NSThread__start__ + 776 (NSThread.m:915)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25754 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001841f1de0 _dlock_wait + 52 (lock.c:326)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001841f1bb8 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow$VARIANT$armv81 + 52 (lock.c:366)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184204560 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 336 (lock.h:330)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018420415c _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 136 (queue.c:1762)
5   UIKitCore                       0x0000000186b7e10c __37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3 + 112 (_UIRemoteKeyboards.m:1065)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844e48e0 __invoking___ + 144
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845005b8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 300 (NSForwarding.m:3378)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000185c3c910 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__ + 20 (NSXPCConnection.m:170)
9   Foundation                      0x0000000185c5c0fc -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 552 (NSXPCConnection.m:316)
10  Foundation                      0x0000000185c3875c __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3 + 208 (NSXPCConnection.m:1630)
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001dde74cc8 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 60 (serializer.c:119)
12  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001dde69004 _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 76 (connection.c:833)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184222368 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 16 (object.m:586)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001841f6808 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 344 (mach.c:2464)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001841fd2e8 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 300 (inline_internal.h:0)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001841fdeec _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 440 (queue.c:3937)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018420776c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 616 (queue.c:6732)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3ef38 _pthread_wqthread + 284 (pthread.c:2495)
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eaa4 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3ea9c _pthread_cond_updateval + 268 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda24b70 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25194 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844caad0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844cebb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844e1d8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Flutter                         0x000000010218de08 0x101ea8000 + 3038728
6   Flutter                         0x000000010218d6c4 0x101ea8000 + 3036868
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda24b70 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25194 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844caad0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844cebb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844e1d8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Flutter                         0x000000010218de08 0x101ea8000 + 3038728
6   Flutter                         0x000000010218d6c4 0x101ea8000 + 3036868
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda24b70 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25194 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844caad0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844cebb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844e1d8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Flutter                         0x000000010218de08 0x101ea8000 + 3038728
6   Flutter                         0x000000010218d6c4 0x101ea8000 + 3036868
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25550 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3f96c _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 1216 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019b6572b8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24 (__threading_support:437)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001021887bc 0x101ea8000 + 3016636
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25550 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3f96c _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 1216 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019b6572b8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24 (__threading_support:437)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001021887bc 0x101ea8000 + 3016636
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25550 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3f96c _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 1216 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019b6572b8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24 (__threading_support:437)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001021887bc 0x101ea8000 + 3016636
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 13 name:
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25550 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3f96c _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 1216 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019b6572b8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24 (__threading_support:437)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001021887bc 0x101ea8000 + 3016636
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 14 name:
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25550 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3f96c _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 1216 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019b6572b8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24 (__threading_support:437)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001021887bc 0x101ea8000 + 3016636
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 15 name:
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda25550 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3f96c _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 1216 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019b6572b8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24 (__threading_support:437)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001021887bc 0x101ea8000 + 3016636
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8

Thread 16 name:
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bda26358 kevent + 8
1   Flutter                         0x00000001022d694c 0x101ea8000 + 4385100
2   Flutter                         0x00000001023040d4 0x101ea8000 + 4571348
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde40458 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:890)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dde3eab0 thread_start + 8


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000140   x5: 0x0000000101847f20   x6: 0x000000000000001c   x7: 0x000000000000003e
    x8: 0x0000000100f88580   x9: 0x1586ebb33258f53a  x10: 0x00000000000007fd  x11: 0x0000000000000001
   x12: 0x0000000000000014  x13: 0x00000000a6e2280d  x14: 0x00000000a7023000  x15: 0x0000000000023000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000003edc  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000103  x21: 0x0000000100f88660  x22: 0x000000016f1829f8  x23: 0x0000000103034e00
   x24: 0x0000000281323014  x25: 0x0000000281323002  x26: 0x0000000102635000  x27: 0x000000010300e5f8
   x28: 0x0000000281322fc0   fp: 0x000000016f182990   lr: 0x00000001dde4a8d8
    sp: 0x000000016f182970   pc: 0x00000001bda2aa48 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
0x100c78000 - 0x100c9bfff Runner arm64  <e654fed9801037009c71928b20d4856b> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C5CB602E-8193-491A-8CC2-510494B02AE7/Runner.app/Runner
0x100f28000 - 0x100f7bfff dyld arm64  <d7a0282e93de3a1e981327e84517cc96> /usr/lib/dyld
0x101ea8000 - 0x1025c7fff Flutter arm64  <f7e47c9752253d4e8010581aeb852efb> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C5CB602E-8193-491A-8CC2-510494B02AE7/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter
0x1841be000 - 0x184240fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <5d722afcfb8c3769bf66167bb94a6133> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1844c4000 - 0x1848fefff CoreFoundation arm64  <fe94d75f5f1d3127ba500161d8817ee6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x185c09000 - 0x185ee7fff Foundation arm64  <b17c0d3bcabb321290560791b2521900> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x186829000 - 0x187fb0fff UIKitCore arm64  <4c9b5192c562355cbfca71961f92935e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x18e972000 - 0x18e9ecfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <b88a565bccaf3f569089e56cdcf1b5e6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x194f24000 - 0x194fc2fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <0d3af6437c5b34afac62d438b1d74315>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?